# SslRequirement.disable_ssl_check error undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, rails-ssl-requirement

I am working on an established project, Rails 3, and trying to turn of SSL in development. The following line in environments/development.rb generates an error.

```
  config.after_initialize do
    SslRequirement.disable_ssl_check = true
  end
```

Error reads:

```
undefined method `disable_ssl_check=' for SslRequirement:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Any pointers to this? 
Searches have revealed little so far.
Thank you

Comment: Which version of the gem do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the version number you provided (`0.1.0`) the problem is likely caused by the fact that you are using a different gem.

The one you use is [ssl_requirement](https://rubygems.org/gems/ssl_requirement) ([repo](https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement)), whereas the `disable_ssl_check` method is provided by [bartt-ssl_requirement](https://rubygems.org/gems/bartt-ssl_requirement) ([repo](https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement)). The latter one is actually a fork of the former one so you might try to upgrade.